# how to implement Scroller in textview for auto scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll

I have used scroller for auto scrolling, but it keeps on scrolling even when text gets over. I want to find the position and want to stop scrolling automatically, so thta text comes to its initial position as during text scrolling text gets over. How can i do this?

The code used for autoscrolling is:

```
public void Scroll()
{
    //text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtView);
    length = text.getLineCount();
    scroll.computeScrollOffset();
    text.setScroller(scroll);
    int a = text.getBottom();
    int b = text.getTop();
    //scroll.extendDuration(scroll.getFinalY());
    scroll.startScroll(scroll_x, scroll_y, 0, a, (500000)/ speedAmount);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikki

You need to check the source code [here](http://bear-polka.blogspot.com/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html) .

> again text must comes to its initial
>   position

for this use `scrollTo(0, 0);`

> i want to find the position

use `scroll.getCurrX();`

> want to stop scrolling automatically

use `scroll.abortAnimation();`

& you are done!:)

EDITED:

Nikki,I wrote a class derived from `Android.Widget.TextView` to customize a TextView in which text can be scrolled until text is finished & after finishing text comes back to initial position.All you need to do is create custom class as defined [here](http://bear-polka.blogspot.com/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html) & just override `computeScroll ()` as below

```
public void computeScroll() {
super.computeScroll();

if (null == mSlr) return;

if (mSlr.isFinished() && (!mPaused)) {
scrollTo(0, 0);//scroll to initial position or whatever position you want it to scroll 
}
}
```

Comment: @Nikki Do you mean to scroll just once? You can use scroll.isFinished() to check whether scrolling text finished & then scroll.abortAnimation() . I hope I am in the right direction in helping you.

Comment: @Nikki I implemented the code & it worked for me.Let me rephrase your problem statement:You want a textview that scrolls until the end of the text & stops scrolling & then show you the text at initial position.

Comment: do you have used isfinished() after startscroll() or somewhere else as isfinished() not working after startscroll()

Comment: what is mPaused variable mean

Comment: @Nikki  didn't you implemented the code at link http://bear-polka.blogspot.com/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html.mPaused is defined there

Comment: you are extending text view while i am using as a part in my activity.Moreover, you are using horzontal scrolling and i am using vertical

Comment: Nikki Did you checked startScroll method it has got options to scroll in any direction you wish so just change startScroll.

Comment: Nikki it seems that you need to rewrite the question to be more understandable & informative

Comment: @100rabh Hi, I've implemented the Scrolling Textview from the link [http://bear-polka.blogspot.in/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html]. But, the textview scrolling is not smooth and appears shaky. Any idea how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question inspired me to blog about this as I had similar problem just some days ago:
http://b.ivity.asia/2010/12/01/extended-marquee-in-android/

I wanted to use a very custom Marquee effect, this class should be able to do the job for you.

Comment: But i want to add vertical scrolling